# Is possible to view users and permissions in the azure portal - CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, user-permissions

I can able to create and set permissions of users in Azure cosmosDB using Rest API and DocumentClient/CosmosClient.

> **But there is no UI part for creating the user under database in Azure portal(cosmosDB) like containers/Collections**

. Is it there or anything I missed?

Thanks, Advanced

Comment: Hi,if my answer helps you,you could mark it for answer,thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, of course, I already marked. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi,thanks for your response. However,you just voted up the answer. Mark means  tick the answer.Thanks.

Comment: OOOh sorry, I did 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,the feature is not supported in the azure cosmos db UI.

You could try to make custom encapsulation of REST API interfaces to obtain user and permissions lists with master key or resource token.

More details,please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data).